# Error executing Linux command using tcl

Tags: tcl

I have the following TCL script which executes a Linux command to format a file.

```
exec sed -r '2,$s/(.{55} )/\1\n\t/g' $formatfileName | sed 's/ $//' > $formatfileName
```

I get an error saying can't read "s": no such variable   while executing
the above line - It is considering $ sign in Linux command as a variable. I tried to put curly braces {} but that did not work.

Can you please advise how to use the above command without errors? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Tcl doesn't use single quotes; the equivalent in Tcl is curly braces (except those nest properly). Also, you need to write to a different file than the one you read in or you get some awkward race conditions between when various bits open the file for reading and for writing that will wipe your file out. (You can rename afterwards.) Something like this should work.

```
exec sed -r {2,$s/(.{55} )/\1\n\t/g} $formatfileName | sed {s/ $//} > $formatfileName.new
file rename -force $formatfileName.new $formatfileName
```

That said, I'd be strongly tempted to do this in pure Tcl (longer, but now portable):

```
set f [open $formatfileName]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

set f [open $formatfileName "w"]
foreach line $lines {
    # First line is special
    if {[incr LN] == 1} {
        puts $f [string trimright $line]
        continue
    }
    foreach l [split [regsub {.{55} } $line "&\n\t"] "\n"] {
        puts $f [string trimright $l]
    }
}
close $f
```

The `string trimright`s are effectively doing what the second `sed` was doing, and the `regsub` in the middle is recognisably similar to the first `sed`, though I'm using an inner `split` there too so that the trimming can be applied consistently.

There's no tricky `file rename` here; the read is definitely preceding the write.

Comment: Also `sed` can be passed multiple patterns to apply on the command line.   You don't need a pipe.

Comment: Thanks a lot Donal Fellows, the modified Linux part with curly braces works like a charm. Thanks for the Tcl code, it is very close to the Linux code. I am trying to learn to make some changes to satisfy the need.

Comment: Thanks Brad Lanam, didn't know that.